# all archive files are set read-only (Ubuntu 10.04 LTS)

Tags: ubuntu

Yesterday I found out that all my archive files (.tar, .zip, .iso etc.) are read-only and I can't do anything with them.

Steps I have tried:

- **reconfiguring and reinstalling** file-roller
- running **chown and chmod 777**
- launching file-roller via **gksudo / sudo**

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Hit Alt+F2 and type gksudo file-roller -> then enter your password. It is command for Super User privilegies (with them may be edited files in the File-roller).

Comment: After running it (gksudo file-roller or sudo file-roller) and selecting the archive, it is still read-only.

Comment: Try "gksudo file-roller -" command.

Comment: That's what I've done.

Comment: Copy gksudo file-roller - (with line) and paste it in command window.